# How to associate a content type with infopath form in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, infopath, content-type

I am working in SharePoint 2010, I have created a new document library with a custom content type. I need to have the content type associate with an existing infopath form. Is there a way that I can associate the form with my new content type so that my content type columns are the same as the fields in the form? I have seen something about being able to create a content type from a form upon creation, but since I did not create the form is there a way to achieve the same result without having to recreate the form?

Comment: Are you going to be storing completed InfoPath forms in the library? Or is your InfoPath form the New/Edit Item form?

Comment: Ideally the form will be the default new item a user can create and then once completed it will be stored in the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you should used a forms library and create your own custom content type that inherits from Document Content Types > Form. There's not a way to do this with an existing content type that inherited from Document. Plus side is, if your fields are already in the inforpath form, all you have to do is promote them when you publish the form to SharePoint.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can this be done at all using a document library instead of a forms library or is using a forms library to store these the only way to accomplish this?

Comment: I think you should just try it the way you want to do it and see if it works. InfoPath stores its data as XML, which is why it works in a Forms library. Using a document library, you won't be able to link metadata in the library to fields in the InfoPath form. You also can't make InfoPath the default file type that would show up when someone tries to add a new item. Really, how I would approach this would depend on why the information is in InfoPath instead of just using a standard SharePoint list and new item form.

Comment: The information is InfoPath due to some of the columns being conditional and having workflows associated with the forms. I don't know much about InfoPath myself, these are just what I was provided to work with. Thanks for the info Erin, much appreciated!